# If one value is NULL then both values are NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, null, notnull

**EDITED FOR CLARITY**

First Part I would like to Have the data automatically changed according to the rule:

For each zone, either both the Area_one and Area_two must be specified, or neither of them are specified ex: either they are both NULL, or neither of them are NULL - Must be table level.

So far I have came up with:

```
constraint chk_Null check (Area_one is not null and Area_two is not null)
```

But with this the script just denies any inserted data that is null.

Second part I would like to automatically change the data according to rule:

For a given Value, when Value_one is present, the Value_two must be NULL (vice versa)

I have written:

```
constraint Value_chk check((Value_one IS NULL and Value_two IS NOT NULL) 
 or (Value_one is NOT NULL and value_two IS NULL))
```

But I am not sure how to finish these off, or if i'm in the right direction.

Thanks all in advanced!

Comment: "Question" is singular on the Stack Overflow site.  Further, `check` constraints do not change the values of columns, only whether rows are valid.  So you cannot do what you want.

Comment: use trigger ? to make them null

Comment: Would there be another way to do this without the check constraint? Thanks(and sorry for two questions, I did not want to spam with multiple posts).

Comment: Q1 is an insert trigger, for Q2 you could use a view instead of the base table. The view can use case to return null if the other column is null. You should be able to find examples easily enough.

Comment: Sounds like an exclusive OR is wanted?  I wonder if the [XOR operator](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_xor.htm) could be used for this.

Answer (score 1):

Both null or neither:

```
constraint chk_Null check (
    (Area_one is not null and Area_two is not null) OR
    (Area_one is null and Area_two is null)
    )
```

To change the data you will have to do it in a trigger, as your regular check constraint will validate data (and might roll it back) but not update it. Your trigger will have to be on insert and update and consider the case when supplied values are both not null (which one will you update?).